# Why was my question protected?

Tags: discussion

As I was browsing my questions today, I noticed [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177305/how-to-express-concern-with-an-unsafe-practice-in-a-hospital-setting-if-quitting) of mine dealing with rationing of ventilators for covid patients to be protected and in status of Highly Active.

I was surprised by this change. First of all, protected questions usually arise due to need to contain trolling answers / non answers or due to flame wars in comments. Neither scenario seems to be the case here. Second of all, I have not seen any new activity on my question that would cause it to be labelled as highly active.

How did these changes come about?

Comment: I can find no reason for it to be protected so I've unprotected it.

Comment: It was protected after it became a hot network question. Back then, I'm not sure what the options were for durations of protection, so it was probably just an oversight that the protection wasn't removed after the activity died down.

Comment: @ColleenV It was protected, not locked. We don't make a habit of unprotecting questions and I can't actually recall ever unprotecting one. Those with high enough reputation can check the [Protected Question List](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions) from the tools.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the log I actually protected it back in 2021. The reason is related to the comment I posted:

> This is a difficult question to address here, partly because it's asked on behalf of someone else but mainly because the medical aspects are likely highly relevant and are mostly outside this site's area of expertise. It's similar to how we do not typically cover situations in Academia. I'd suggest to all would-be-answers to stick to the workplace aspects of this question since we can't address medical decision making here.

It was pre-emptively protected because it had hit HNQ and due to the subject matter. The drive-by posters that HNQ attracts tend not to respect site guidelines very well and are much more likely to soapbox in the answers where potentially divisive topics are concerned.

When we protect a question the example rationale describes it well: "*This question is highly active and likely to receive spam activity or non-answers (e.g. "Me too!" "Thanks!"). Anonymous and low reputation users can’t answer protected questions.*".

> First of all, protected questions usually arise due to need to contain trolling answers / non answers or due to flame wars in comments.

So it was to prevent the former. Note that comment wars are what question *locks* are for, not protection.